# Can't get WordPress to write error messages to the debug log

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I can't get WordPress to write error messages to the debug log.
In my `wp-config.php`, I have:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

I set the permissions of `wp-content` to `777` and of `debug.log` (that I created) to `666`, but still no luck.
Setting `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `true` does make the errors display, and so do things like `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` etc, but the log is never written.
Using the `error_log` function doesn't work either.

What could be the cause of this and how could I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was an annoyingly easy issue - it actually is writing to the log, but I was looking at the wrong place. Be sure to check not only the WordPress root, but the `wp-admin`, `wp-includes`, and especially the `wp-content` folders for error log files.

By default, [the error log is set to `wp-content/error.log`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log), but you can change it using the following line in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/some-path/error-file.log' );
```